# javascript wont allow me to set a variable to an operator( + - / *)

Tags: javascript, operator-keyword, jquery-mobile

So I am trying to randomize whether I am adding or subtracting.  right now in this code what should happen is when I navigate to the #second page the code will load a new Problem is created.  Inside the Problem function is should get a random number 0 or 1 and then based on that number the variable symbol should be set to a plus sign or a minus sign.
This is not occurring.

So my question is: Can I set a variable to a javascript operator sign?

In this code below it never writes to the screen because it doesnt like me to set a variable to a + - sign?
code in question:

```
$(document).delegate("#second", "pageshow", function(){
    var problem = new Problem;
    function Problem (){

            var num = Math.floor(Math.random()*2);
            var symbol;
             if(num)
                symbol = +;
            else
                symbol = -;
            $(".random").html(num + "  " + symbol); 


    }
});
```

here is my html:

```
</script>
    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">

        <h1>Hello</h1>
    </div><!-- /header -->

    <div data-role="content" id="timer">
         <a href="#main" data-role="button">main</a> 
         <p class="random"></p>         
    </div><!-- /content -->

    <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
        <h4>Goodbye</h4>
    </div><!-- /footer -->

</div><!-- /page -->
```

sorry should have mentioned that I actually want to use the operators later therefore I need to be able to assign the + or - is such a way that I can then perform legal math operations with them later.

Comment: You need to learn what a _string_ is.

Comment: If you just had bothered to see the console, it would have told you: `Syntax error` and pointed to the line `symbol = +;`...

Comment: I havent tried putting it in a string because...wouldnt I then have to parse that string later to actually use the + or - sign operator to perform legal math operations?

Comment: @BigT In that case you better edit your question and ask rather how to achieve what you really want, instead of this simple syntax error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't assign operators, but you can create functions that perform operations and assign the functions.

```
var operations = {
  plus: function(a, b) { return a + b; },
  minus: function(a, b) { return a - b; }
};
```

Now you can assign `operations.plus` or `operations.minus` to another variable:

```
var op = operations[ operationName ];
```

If you then want to perform the operation:

```
var answer = op( input1, input2 );
```

Comment: Exactly where I was going after the new comment about having to parse it later.

Answer (score 1):

So you want… a string?

```
if(num)
    symbol = "+";
else
    symbol = "-";
```

Strings are for text, and you need one string of text or another.

Comment: I thought about that but wouldnt I have to parse that later to actually use it to perform addition or subtraction?

Comment: @BigT: You could. The alternative, of course, is it not working at all. But if you have the details of the problem to begin with, why not just store the result in your `Problem` object?

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the operator in a string "+" or "-" or "*" or "/"

```
symbol = "+";
```

No you can't assign operators to variables